# WKInterfaceLabel.setText not reflecting changes following modal viewController dismissal

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, watchkit, watchos-2

I am working on a simple video game for the Apple Watch. In awakeWithContext() I call my own method, startNewGame(), and register for it to be called again when receiving a notification from my modal viewController. This all works fine. Then upon determining the game is over, I call self.presentControllerWithName().
When that controller is dismissed by the player I call self.dismissController(). Then I fire a notification that once again calls startNewGame(). This is where things get weird.

```
self.score = 0
let scoreString = formatScore(0) //"0000"
self.scoreboard.setText(scoreString)
let hiScore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("hiScore")
let hiScoreString = formatScore(hiScore)
self.hiScoreboard.setText(hiScoreString)
```

The above excerpt from startNewGame() shows me resetting the score and updating both "scoreboards" both WKInterfaceLabels that present scores in a skeumorphic old-timey LCD fashion. Because of this, I call formatScore() which returns a string with leading zeros. Anyway, I then set the text on them both and… nothing happens. Both boards show the same score as before the game over view controller was shown. It is only when they are next updated in response to player's actions that they update to reflect the correct values. Because I only have issues with this when the code runs shortly following the dismissal of a modal viewController, I suspect there is some connection. Anyway, I am stumped, some help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried to dispatch to the main queue to update the text label?

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       
});

Comment: Doesn't code run on the main thread unless specified otherwise?

Comment: Nope, I plopped the code in the block, no change.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem receiving data from the iPhone using `sendMessage`.

My code was pretty straight forward:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
  if let error = error {
    NSLog("showing error: \(error)");
    self.lblTitle.setText("Error...");
  } 
});
```

For me, the message was being logged, but the interface wasn't getting updated.

Ends up I was showing multiple pages using `reloadRootControllersWithNames` and when I tried to update a label within a page that wasn't being shown, the update was ignored.

I fixed it by listening to `willActivate` and `didDeactivate` to see whether to update the label or whether to save the text so I could apply it when the page is shown.

Apparently this is [by design](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8365).